# Getting 'microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity' error in azure active directory authentication in xamarin forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I have tried to implement Microsoft azure active directory authentication in Xamarin forms. I have face a problem in redirect to app after enter the credentials. Please suggest any idea to fix this problem.

Here is the exception I have got:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname.AppName/microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.AppName-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.AppName-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

### Sample code:

```
   authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)
                                                  .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow).ExecuteAsync();

   await GetUserDetails(authResult.AccessToken).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

### Manifest file :

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:installLocation="auto"> 

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application android:label="AppName.Android">

  <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">

  <!--android:launchMode="singleTop" android:noHistory="true"-->

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="msala{AppId}" android:host="auth" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

Comment: In the microsoft documentation, it is said to use "com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" in the manifest, I have removed the "COM" and it worked for me.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android#configure-your-application